# Radio Button no WinForm - Como Consultar No Banco Firebird

Tags: winforms

Olá.
Tenho um cadastro de cliente onde no campo CPF/CNPJ tenho 2 RadioButton onde ao selecionar CPF a aplicação pela Mask apresenta a quantidade de campos para CPF e quando é selecionado o RadioButton CNPJ apresenta a quantidade de campos para CNPJ.
Consigo gravar sem problemas no meu banco Firebird, minha trava é na consulta, quando clico na DataGridView para ir na aba Manutenção onde esta a tela de cadastro, o RadioButton não carrega corretamente conforme foi gravado.
Tentei colocar um IF se o campo possuir mais que 14 dígitos trazer marcado o campo CNPJ mas mesmo assim não funcionou, pois quando carrega vem marcado o CNPJ e sem os dados do CNPJ e quando volto na consulta e consulto a mesma empresa carrega incompleto.
Obs.: Quando salvo no banco CPF = 0 e CNPJ = 1

["IMG" CNPJ na primeira consulta trazendo vazio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXKfR.png)
["IMG" CNPJ na segunda consulta com dígitos faltantes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPV7m.png)

```
            if (dtConsulta.Rows.Count > 0)

            {
                this.MN_txtCodigo.Text = dtConsulta.Rows[0]["COD"].ToString();
                this.MN_txtNome.Text = dtConsulta.Rows[0]["NOME"].ToString();
                this.MN_txtEndereco.Text = dtConsulta.Rows[0]["ENDERECO"].ToString();
                this.MN_txtNumero.Text = dtConsulta.Rows[0]["NUMERO"].ToString();
                this.MN_txtBairro.Text = dtConsulta.Rows[0]["BAIRRO"].ToString();
                this.MN_maskCep.Text = dtConsulta.Rows[0]["CEP"].ToString();

                this.MN_maskCPF_CNPJ.Mask = dtConsulta.Rows[0]["CPF_CNPJ"].ToString();

                
                if (Convert.ToDecimal(this.MN_maskCPF_CNPJ.Mask) > 99999999999999)
                {
                    this.MN_radBtnCNPJ.Checked = true;
                }

                else
                {
                    this.MN_radBtnCPF.Checked = true;
                }
                
                this.MN_maskTelefone.Text = dtConsulta.Rows[0]["FONE"].ToString();
                this.MN_cmbTipo.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(dtConsulta.Rows[0]["TIPO"].ToString());
```

---

```
// Essa é a parte que salvo o CPF & CNPJ no Banco Firebird

            if (this.MN_radBtnCPF.Checked)
            {
                sqcIncluir.Parameters.Add("@TP_CPF_CNPJ", FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDbType.SmallInt).Value = this.MN_radBtnCPF.Text = "0";
                this.MN_radBtnCPF.Text = "CPF";

            }

            else
            {
                sqcIncluir.Parameters.Add("@TP_CPF_CNPJ", FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDbType.SmallInt).Value = this.MN_radBtnCNPJ.Text = "1";
                this.MN_radBtnCNPJ.Text = "CNPJ";

            }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Entendi o que estava acontecendo, fiz a mudança no script e funcionou.
Espero que ajude quem um dia precisar.

```
if (dtConsulta.Rows.Count > 0)

            {
                this.MN_txtCodigo.Text = dtConsulta.Rows[0]["COD"].ToString();
                this.MN_txtNome.Text = dtConsulta.Rows[0]["NOME"].ToString();
                this.MN_txtEndereco.Text = dtConsulta.Rows[0]["ENDERECO"].ToString();
                this.MN_txtNumero.Text = dtConsulta.Rows[0]["NUMERO"].ToString();
                this.MN_txtBairro.Text = dtConsulta.Rows[0]["BAIRRO"].ToString();
                this.MN_maskCep.Text = dtConsulta.Rows[0]["CEP"].ToString();                   

                
                if (dtConsulta.Rows[0]["CPF_CNPJ"].ToString().Length <= 11)
                {
                    this.MN_radBtnCPF.Checked = true; 
                }
                else
                {
                    this.MN_radBtnCNPJ.Checked = true;
                }

                this.MN_maskCPF_CNPJ.Text = dtConsulta.Rows[0]["CPF_CNPJ"].ToString();
                this.MN_maskTelefone.Text = dtConsulta.Rows[0]["FONE"].ToString();
                this.MN_cmbTipo.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(dtConsulta.Rows[0]["TIPO"].ToString());
```